# Use text digits in math mode

Tags: math-mode, environments, math-fonts, mathastext

I am trying to typeset an old math paper that uses the text digits instead of the math digits in equations. E.g.

[image]

However, `mathastext` loads the math digits font from the `baskervillef` package in math environments by default. How can I change the default math digits font to the text digits font in math environments? Are there any solutions that do not require `XeLaTeX`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[p,osf]{baskervillef}
\usepackage[basic, frenchmath]{mathastext}

\begin{document}
Text digit: $i \neq n + \text{1}$

Math digit: $i \neq n + 1$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can declare the text font as a Math symbol font, then set up the digits to use it

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[p,osf]{baskervillef}

\DeclareSymbolFont{digits}{T1}{BaskervilleF-OsF}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`7}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`9}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


Text digit: $i \neq n + \text{1}$

Math digit: $i \neq n + 1$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I do something similar with the text symbols? Say if I want to change the font of the text parantheses to another SymbolFont?

Comment: yes you can do exactly the same except `\( ` would be `\mathopen` not `\mathalpha`  but perhaps you don't really want to change the digits to a new font perhaps what you really wanted to do was change the operator font to be that font, so then digits, () `\log`  `\mathrm{..}` wold all use the text roman font. @FR09

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, what I wanted to ask is whether there is a command (similar to ```\DeclareMathSymbol```) that is used to declare text symbols instead of math symbols.

Comment: oh sorry no. There is not. @FR09 only by making characters active, but if you make digits active nothing will work